# lme4/Matrix: Entry Point Not Found - how to fix?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lme4, mixed-models

I have been using `lme4` every day for quite a while.

Today, after opening `R` (x64 v 2.15.1), it complained that `there is no package called ‘lme4’`. So I re-installed it.

When I ran `require(lme4)` a popup was generated saying `Entry Point Not Found. The procedure entry point Rf_copyListMatrix could not be location in the dynamic link library R.dll` and after clicking OK the message there was an error in the `R` console:

```
Error: package ‘Matrix’ could not be loaded
```

So I reinstalled Matrix, after running `require(Matrix)` the same popup is generated followed by this error in the console

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/R/R-2.15.1/library/Matrix/libs/x64/Matrix.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have tried restarting R and rebooting the PC.

How can I fix this ?

**Update**:
sessionInfo() gives the following:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lattice_0.20-10
```

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.1

Comment: Are you in a position to build from source (i.e., do you have Rtools installed)?  I would probably try installing Matrix, then installing `lme4` from source -- seems as though you've got some sort of version mismatch thing going on.  Results of `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: @BenBolker I have updated the question with `sessionInfo()` output. I don't use Rtools..

Comment: @BenBolker is there anything else I can provide to make this question more answerable ? I tried re-installing R yesterday and it was fine until I quit the session and the next session had the same problem again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now solved this problem.

It required a minor upgrade of R from v 2.15.1 to 2.15.2